# Running setup.exe as non admin doesn't throw any error

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

When a non-admin user tries to install setup.exe it should throw the below error message as per our Installshield condition.

"You did not log on as Administrator or have required permissions to install "

But recently when we tried to install setup as non-admin it didn't throw any error. When Setup.exe is executed, nothing happens.

Condition:
AdminUser AND Privileged : message -> You did not log on as Administrator or have required permissions to install

Initially we thought some windows update could have caused the issue. But when I created a sample setup.exe it throws the error. How to identify why my setup.exe stopped to throw the error message.

Note : No file generated in %temp% folder when running setup.exe. If we double click or, giving Run as Admin nothing happens. Also Requires Administrative Privileges is given Yes.

Comment: I can't test this right now, but are there any other settings that conflict with this "`Requires Administrative Privileges`" setting? I would first try to use the `Release Wizard` to create a new release and test if that release works as expected.

Comment: On second read I see you have tried the test `setup.exe` approach. Was that a test project, or a new release in your problem file? Do you clone existing releases to create new ones? I suppose you need to compare - in detail - the release and configuration property pages between the working setup.exe release and the one that does not work. Maybe you already did?

Comment: Is this an Installscript MSI? Maybe you have the "***Highest Available***" flag on instead of the "***Administrator***" option as [described in the documentation](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/helplibrary/SpecifyingRequiredExecution.htm).

Comment: Yes this is an Installscript MSI and the "Administrator" flag is set.

Comment: We do clone the existing releases. We just change the version number. The weird thing here is, the previous versions which used to throw the error message (that you are not admin error message) is not throwing now. So there is no change in the release and configuration property.

Answer (score 0):

While the AdminUser and Privileged properties used to tell you what you're asking for, they were altered for the introduction of UAC. The theory is that in most cases a Windows Installer package would elevate in the InstallExecute phase, while its UI would be run as a limited user. Since this wasn't typically done before UAC (though it was possible with advertisement), Microsoft altered the behavior of these properties for better backwards compatibility.

There is a way to request the original meaning of these properties: set [MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/msiuserealadmindetection) to 1.

However, if you rely on this to prevent installation, you're not doing things the way Microsoft expects you to do them. You should instead fix whatever's broken when your installation is not launched with full admin privileges, and then you can remove your check. If there's already nothing broken, then just remove the check. Windows Installer will only install as a limited user if you specifically enable it by your authoring. (See ALLUSERS, MSIINSTALLPERUSER, and the rest of [Single Package Authoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/single-package-authoring) for the more recent approach, or, before that, bit 3 of the [Word Count Summary property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/word-count-summary), which when set to the typical 0 requires elevation.)

As far as logging goes, setup.exe and Windows Installer will only log if requested, either by command line, authoring, or policy. Use the command line (elevated or otherwise, depending on which scenario you want to test), and run something like this: `setup.exe /debuglog /v"/l*v c:\users\me\desktop\setup.log"`